# Terminal: changing colors

Tags: terminal

I'm a newbie trying out some stuff on my terminal.
I've searched and learned a few ways to tweak my terminal by modifying .bash_profile and .bashrc files. I've referenced some codes from github, but I can't seem to customize the very first part of my title that reads 
*(base)* . I don't even know what this is called, is it current working directory? I don't think so, since it's not a directory, it must be some kind of environment thing bc it changes with conda activate 'environment name'. I'm curious if this part has a variable so I can customize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `PS1` variable controls the prompt in bash. conda automatically prepends the environment name to your PS1 variable which is why you see "base". You can disable `changeps` to prevent that.

See here: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#change-command-prompt-changeps1

You might also need to disable `auto_activate_base` with:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

For general customization of `PS1`, there are a few online generators such as http://bashrcgenerator.com/.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me some tips on how I can change colors instead of actually removing "base" though? I'm looking at the modified .bash_profile and but can't find figure out how. Sorry I feel like I'm bugging you with something really not that important